# Core Data Migration Error: Can't Copy

Tags: objective-c, core-data, rubymotion

I'm really stuck on a `Core Data` error that I can't seem to solve:

```
Can't migrate SQLite store: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.) UserInfo=0xab4b630 {NSUnderlyingError=0xab4b2e0 The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.), reason=Can't copy source store to destination store path
```

I can't find any resources about this error...

Its a pretty simple migration, just one model "User" with name property and created_by property and for my test I didn't change anything, both models are the same. I just want to get it working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Two people have marked this down... some comments on how to make this question better would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error was caused by me attempting to migrate data to a sql store that already existed. On top of that, I didn't load the original store with the persistent coordinator first.

So lessons learned:

1. Your destination should be a path that doesn't exist yet. It will create it for you.
2. Load your original store (the one you want to migrate from) first, before attempting to migrate.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: I'm a beginner to CoreData, Can you tell me how to load original store first?